# npm start すると SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL と表示される

Tags: node.js, npm

プログラマ初心者です。
"npm start"をした際に以下のエラーが出るのですが、なにがだめなのか見当もつきません。だいたいこの辺が良くないという大まかなご助言だけでもいいので、どうかご教授お願いいたします。

```
$ npm start
 プロジェクト名-keystone@0.0.0 start /vagrant/プロジェクト名
 node keystone.js

/vagrant/プロジェクト名/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js:67

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/alq/keystone.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
```

「補足」
`npm start`すると以下のエラーが上記にのさらに続きます。

```
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/bin/npm" "start"  
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! alq-keystone@0.0.0 start: `node keystone.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the alq-keystone@0.0.0 start script 'node keystone.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the alq-keystone package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node keystone.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs プロジェクト名-keystone
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls プロジェクト名-keystone
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/alq/npm-debug.log
```

また`keystone.js`は以下の通りになっております

```
// Simulate config options from your production environment by
 // customising the .env file in your project's root folder.
 require('dotenv').config();

// Require keystone
var keystone = require('keystone');

// Initialise Keystone with your project's configuration.
// See http://keystonejs.com/guide/config for available options
// and documentation.

keystone.init({
'name': 'プロジェクト名-keystone',
'brand': 'プロジェクト名-keystone',

'sass': 'public',
'static': 'public',
'favicon': 'public/favicon.ico',
'views': 'templates/views',
'view engine': 'jade',

'emails': 'templates/emails',

'auto update': true,
'session': true,
'auth': true,
'user model': 'User',

'cloudinary config': process.env.CLOUDINARY_URL || ''
});

// Load your project's Models
    keystone.import('models');

// Setup common locals for your templates. The following are required for the
// bundled templates and layouts. Any runtime locals (that should be set uniquely
// for each request) should be added to ./routes/middleware.js
 keystone.set('locals', {
_: require('lodash'),
env: keystone.get('env'),
utils: keystone.utils,
editable: keystone.content.editable,
});

// Load your project's Routes
keystone.set('routes', require('./routes'));

// Setup common locals for your emails. The following are required by Keystone's
// default email templates, you may remove them if you're using your own.
keystone.set('email locals', {
logo_src: '/images/logo-email.gif',
logo_width: 194,
logo_height: 76,
theme: {
    email_bg: '#f9f9f9',
    link_color: '#2697de',
    buttons: {
color: '#fff',
background_color: '#2697de',
border_color: '#1a7cb7',
},
},
});

// Load your project's email test routes
 keystone.set('email tests', require('./routes/emails'));


// Configure the navigation bar in Keystone's Admin UI
keystone.set('nav', {
    posts: ['posts', 'post-categories'],
    galleries: 'galleries',
    enquiries: 'enquiries',
    users: 'users',
});

// Start Keystone to connect to your database and initialise the web server
```

[補足]
`main.js`の67行目以降

`^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@5M-^O^@?H^O,?HM-^IE^HH?^@^@^@^@^@^`

Comment: `dotenv`というモジュールがエラーを出していますね。これは`process.env` をパースする物のようですが、こういったファイルがプロジェクトにありますか？

Comment: `process.env`をパースする物というのはどういうことなのでしょうか？(汗)。`process.env`をファイル検索かけてみましたが、見つからなかったのでプロジェクトにないと思います。

Comment: なるほど。勘違いしたみたいです。`npm start`した時なにが行なわれるかは`package.json`で設定されますが、ここで`node keystone.js`を実行しているのでしょうか。エラーの元は`keystone.js`ですかね。中身を見ないとエラーの原因の推測は難しいと思います。`KeystoneJS`というCMSを使っていますか？ もし秘密でないなら、そういった事も書いた方がよいです。

Comment: 質問の項目に補足を追加しました。エラーの内容を見る限り`keystone.js`でエラーが出ているのだと思います。

Comment: やはり、`keystone.js`の3行目で呼ばれた`dotenv`のエラーのようです。`.env file in your project's root folder` という事ですので、設定ファイルは`.env`というファイル名でしたね。ドット始まりのファイル名（ドットファイル）なので注意して探して見て下さい。`ls -a`でドットファイルも表示されます。

Comment: 夜分恐れ入ります。ということは`.env`ファイルに問題があるということでしょうか？

Comment: `.env`があったなら、かなりの確率でそれが原因です。`dotenv`というモジュールにバグがある可能性もありますが。

Comment: 承知しました。とりあえず`.env`ファイルと`dotenv`モジュールあたりを調べていきたいと思います。色々お世話になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: `dotenv`というモジュールを少し見てみたのですが、`.env`を読むといってもevalするわけでもないし、`.env`が原因で構文エラーにはならなそうです。ですから、`.env`に原因がある可能性が高いというのは撤回いたします。

Comment: `dotenv/lib/main.js`にJavaScriptで許可されないが、通常表示されない空白文字である、という厄介な文字が紛れこんだのではないか、というのが現在の予想です。`main.js`の文字コードをダンプさせてみる位やらないと、原因は分からないかもしれません。簡単な方法としては、`cat`に`-v`オプションを渡すとコントロール文字なども可視化してくれるので、`cat -nv node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js` として67行目付近を見てみるという手があります。

Comment: お返事が遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。mjy様がおっしゃる通り`main.js`の67行目にはよくわからない文字列が連なっていました。その文字列は補足に追加しました。この文字列は削除してもよろしいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

壊れた`dotenv`モジュールの復旧は、削除して再インストールするのが早いです。

```
rm -r node_modules/dotenv/
npm install dotenv
```

しかし、壊れているのは`dotenv`だけなのか、なぜ壊れたのか、が分かりませんね。
心あたりが無ければ、ファイルシステムの不具合やストレージの故障もあり得ると思います。

少し気になるのは、Vagrantの共有フォルダを使って作業なさっている様子な事です。
（私はここらへんは常用していないので分かりませんが、NginxやApacheとの組み合わせでトラブルを起す事は[あるようです](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/virtualbox.html)。）

Comment: `dotenv`を削除して再インストールしましたが、それでも`npm start`でうまくいきませんでした。色々削除しては再インストールを繰り返しているのですが、きりがありません。`node_module`以下の階層のファイルがエラーを起こしているようなのですが、どうすればよろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: @Kanba  `node_m‌​odule`以下全て削除して`nom install`で再インストールしてみてもよいですが、ファイルシステムの問題ならまたファイルが壊れるかもしれません。その場合はVagrantの共有ディレクトリでは**無い**場所で一からインストールして作業してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: `npm install node_module`で再インストールしてみたのですが、やはりダメでしたので１からインストールをしてみようと思います。

Comment: ちなみにVagrantの共有ディレクトリではなく普通はどのディレクトリで作業すべきなのでしょうか？Vagrantを使った開発は初めてなのでわからない事だらけで申し訳ないですが、宜しくお願いします。

Comment: とりあえずホームディレクトリ以下とかでよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 承知しました。引き続き1からインストールを進めてみようと思います。

Comment: @miy 先日問題解決しました。はっきりとした原因は特定していないのですが、以下の事を修正したら解決しました。

・`vagrant ssh` をする
・作業ディレクトリを共有ディレクトリからホームディレクトリに変更する事

前者についてはお恥ずかしながら自分の初歩的なミスでした。もしかしたらこれが原因でできていなかったのかもしれません。